# Decimal numbers and currency formatting in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select .5 as colm from dual;
```

gives `0.5` as the output

But

```
select .5||'$' as colm from dual;
```

gives `.5$` as the result. Why I am not getting `0.5$`

How can I achieve `0.5$` in the second query?

Comment: Hint: it's up to the client how to display numbers.

Comment: In the target table the values is loaded as `0.5$`, So when I do a minus it fails, So is there any way like converting to string or casting the data type?

Comment: @sure https://duckduckgo.com/?q=oracle+convert+number+to+string&t=ffsb&ia=qa But what's the use case, how comes you've reached that situation?

Comment: Not clear what you need. The `||` operator coerces both operands to strings; do you want to have an actual number there? A decimal, maybe (since it is money)? Are you planning to do arithmetic with it? Keep it as a decimal until you need to actually show it!

Comment: @User9213 I want to concatenate the value with the symbol, by keeping the number as decimal, `0` before the `.`  Datatype of the resultant column can be any

Comment: But where is the `.5` coming from? Is a user typing it in, or will it come from a table?

Comment: It is coming from table. For an example I have given `.5`, it can be `2.5` or `0` etc..

Comment: It comes from a table? Are you sure it is a `NUMBER`? Is it possible that it's a `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: Its a number column. /the solution suggested bu MT0 is working

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi Sorry, I should have tested it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( value ) AS
  SELECT 0.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5   FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         TO_CHAR( value, 'FM9999999990.99' ),
         '\.$'
       ) || '$' AS formatted_value,
       CASE
         WHEN TRUNC( value ) = value
         THEN TO_CHAR( value, '9999999990' )
         ELSE TO_CHAR( value, 'FM9999999990.99' )
       END || '$' AS alternate_value,
       TO_CHAR( value, '9999999990.99L' ) AS currency_value
FROM   your_table;
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE FORMATTED_VALUE ALTERNATE_VALUE CURRENCY_VALUE
----- --------------- --------------- --------------
  0.5 0.5$            0.5$            0.50$
    5 5$              5$              5.00$
```

Comment: `regex` is simply too much for this.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar If the OP wants an optional decimal point then they will have to do some processing to determine whether the decimal point is necessary. I've added a non-regular expression option that gives the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appending, we can do like below. Format the currency in expected format.

```
select TO_CHAR(.5,'FM999999990.099999999$') as colm from dual;
```

Otherwise, you still can concat the currency symbol like,

```
select TO_CHAR(.5,'FM999999990.099999999')||'$' as colm from dual;
```

Key is you have to explicitly mention the number format before concatenating.

Format models are well-covered in the documentation. [Read it here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211).

Comment: Can you tell me what is `FM0.99999999` in this context?

Comment: `select TO_CHAR(5,'FM0.99999999')||'$' as new_col from dual` It gives me just 5.$

Comment: Just play with the available formats, that match your preferences `FM999999990.99999999$`

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi - your format mask is different from that of MaheswaranRavisankar . Check the first character after the decimal point

Comment: @APC NLS Parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Do you like to write `$` as a constant string or is it your local currency symbol (US-Dollars)?

In later case, this solution may work for you:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(0.5555, 'fm999999990D99L') from dual;
```

See [TO_CHAR - Number Format Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#r12c1-t60):

> - L
>     Returns in the specified position the local currency symbol (the
>     current value of the NLS_CURRENCY parameter).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot concatenate a "NUMBER" field with a String field.

In your case .5 is a number and '$' is a string. So if you want your result to be '0.5$' you have to pass 0.5 as a string as below:-

```
select '0.5'||'$' as colm from dual;
```

Comment: `with src as
(select .5 as colm from dual)
select colm||'$' as new_col from src` In such case this trick wont help

Comment: It will ALWAYS work, as I said before you CANNOT concatenate a number with a string. Both have to be strings. For the above query, you can use

`with src as (select '0.5' as colm from dual) select colm||'$' as new_col from src`

Comment: If you only have to concatenate with .5 and not '0.5' then convert .5 into a string by doing  **TO_CHAR(.5)** in oracle or **cast(.5 as varchar)** in mssql.

Comment: `SELECT 0.5 || '$' FROM DUAL` works and Oracle will perform an implicit `TO_CHAR()` on the number. "You cannot concatenate a "NUMBER" field with a String field." is incorrect.

Comment: @MT0 So how can I achieve the result. Any work around?